# Minimise $ x^2 +y^2 + z^2 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $2x+3y+4z=5$, find the minimum value of $x^2 +y^2 +z^2$.
If I use AM-GM on $x,x,y,2y,2z$ and $2z$, I get the answer as $\frac {5^6}{(8×6^6)}$.
But the answer given by my book is $\frac {25}{29}$.
Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your AM-GM says that $$\frac{x + x + y + 2y + 2z + 2z}{6}\geq \sqrt[6]{8x^2y^2z^2}$$ However, we're not interested in $x^2y^2z^2$. We're interested in $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$.

One possible solutioon: The smallest possible value of $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$ on the plane will correspond to a sphere centered at the origin tangent to the given plane. In other words, we're after the distance from the plane to the origin. To find that, we first normalize the equation for the plane (rewrite it so it has a unit normal vector). We have $2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 = 29$, so the new equation for the plane is
$$
\frac2{\sqrt{29}}x + \frac3{\sqrt{29}}y + \frac4{\sqrt{29}}z = \frac{5}{\sqrt{29}}
$$
For a normalized plane equation, the distance to the origin is simply the constant term, which is $\frac5{\sqrt{29}}$. This corresponds to the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = \frac{25}{29}$

Comment: Is it assumed to be $$x,y,z\geq 0$$ I could not find that condition!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Could you be a bit more specific? Why is that relevant?

Comment: It is a condition for using AM-GM!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner I gave one reason why the AM-GM approach is wrong. you're free to give others. I don't see how that makes me incorrect.

Comment: Ok, now i understand, sorry for that!

Comment: Thanks, I get it. But just to clarify that should be 5/sqrt(29) right? In the last step.

Comment: @PranavAggarwal Yes, that was a typo, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use Cauchy Schwarz: $$(2x+3y+4z)^2\le (4+9+16)(x^2+y^2+z^2)$$

Comment: Thank you, but could you please explain why my method is incorrect?

Comment: @Arthur - you are correct. Deleted my comment so as not to confuse

Comment: He is not correct, he needs that $$x,y,z\geq 0$$!